# Issue with Opening of PDF file in Java

Tags: java, pdf

I tried to use the following code for opening of the PDF file, but its not working. I tried to use the run time but still not opening. Even after debugging it is invoking the open() w/o any exception still, no sign of the pdf. What Have i done wrong?

```
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1)
            {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File myFile = new File("Doc.pdf");
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is that file exists? is that `try` block executing? any error?

Comment: Yes, that file does exists.

Comment: @bshah are you sure that there is no errors ?after the line `Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);` add a sout `Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);System.out.println("open")`
then run again and see the output and can you manuallly open that pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem, I had a problem with my pdf viewer. Had to re-install it, now the code works just great.

Comment: yes, after your comment i did check that out. thanks